# How to center a composable in the middle of the visible part of a LazyColumn item

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn

I have a specific use case where I'm dealing with a LazyColumn containing swipeable items of varying heights. My objective is to center the background of the swipeable composable on the visible part of the currently swiped item. This becomes necessary because certain items in the list might be taller than the screen's entire height. If I were to simply center the background based on the middle of the item, it could end up being partially or completely out of view:

[image]

This is a gist that is reproducing the issue from the gif above:
https://gist.github.com/leinardi/7b256eae5584d647e229c9120894c581

An implementation of what I would like to achieve is visible inside the app Relay for Reddit:

[image]

Comment: Can you please share a code?

Comment: I'm not sure which code you want to see since I have no clue on how to center the background inside the item, but I made this gits that allows you to reproduce the issue if you swipe to dismiss every 2nd item (the trashcan is not visible unless you scroll down):
https://gist.github.com/leinardi/7b256eae5584d647e229c9120894c581